# What is the meaning of 及 in the compound word 危及?

Tags: vocabulary, etymology

I know 及 as a conjungtion for words or phrases with the meaning "and". 
What meaning does 及 bear here that makes semantically sense?

Comment: verb: endanger, look it up in a dictionary, e.g. iciba, compare with 涉及 involve, relate to,etc, and there are more such compounds with 及 as second morpheme

Comment: ３ more similar compounds 遍及，波及，顾及， due to （one） meaning （义项 ２ in HSK dictionary）of 及：reach， come to

Comment: another one that occurs quite often： 提及，for more could consult 小马词典 http://www.xiaoma.info/compound.php?uni=%E5%8F%8A&fhz=%E5%8F%8A&fpy=%E9%A1%BE%E5%8F%8A unfortunately there does not seem to be a 倒序汉语词典／Reverse Chinese Dictionary online

Comment: @S.Rhee You really should use the answer text box more often. Comments are usually reserved for discussions about the question itself, like complementing, correcting, etc.

Answer (score 5):

`及` means `to reach`. Some examples:

> 及格: to pass a test. Literally 'to reach the bar'.
>
> 长发及腰: 'long hair reaching waistline'.
>
> 涉及: to involve. Literally 'intervention reaches to'.
>
> 提及: to mention. Literally '(the scope of) mentioning reaches to'.
>
> 力所能及: within grasp. Literally 'capability that (one) can reach'.